# Up-to-date survey of panel data models

Tags: reference-request, paneldata

I am looking for an **up-to-date survey paper** or a book chapter on **panel data models**.

I know there are excellent textbooks out there like

- Wooldridge ["Econometric analysis of cross section and panel data"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/econometric-analysis-cross-section-and-panel-data-second-edition) (2nd edition, 2010) and
- Hsiao ["Analysis of Panel Data"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/analysis-of-panel-data/A774C63FF969DA1944A3F91501702C65) (3rd edition, 2014)*,

but I am looking for a briefer introduction/overview. Among survey papers,

- Baltagi & Raj ["A Survey of Recent Theoretical Developments in the Econometrics of Panel Data"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01192477) (1992) is no longer recent.
- Chudik & Pesaran ["Large Panel Data Models with Cross-Sectional Dependence: A Survey"](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/80496/1/cesifo_wp4371.pdf) (2013) is more recent but seemingly a bit narrow and rather technical.

*Chapter 13 looks pretty nice as it summarizes the entire book; it might be a good starting point.

Comment: This is partly motivated by a current need to deal with panel data. Having no prior experience, I am looking for an efficient way to find out what model applies to my data and how to estimate it. I would like to avoid making beginner's mistakes (or at least too many of them), thus the reference request.

Comment: hmm I know some good books, but not really anything brief. Panel data is nowadays quite a big field - usually you will have separate chapters for panel IV, panel logit/probit, panel time series etc.

Comment: @1muflon1, unfortunately, I must say your comment makes sense. Panel data indeed seems to have become a vast field, so anything less than a textbook might be insufficient. Wooldridge and Hsiao books both look solid; I guess I might need to take a closer look at them.

Comment: If you plan to be working with panels with large T I would recommend Pesaran, Time Series and Panel Data Econometrics over the Wooldridge text which focuses more on traditional panel data with large N and (relatively) small T. Also Verbeek guide to modern econometrics has *relatively* brief overview of common panel data models but still its covered over multiple chapters

Comment: @1muflon1, thanks! My current problem has a small T.

Comment: then Pesaran won't be as good, although I just checked the Verbeek and that one focuses on panels with short T also I originally thought its across multiple chapters but it turns out I just miss-remembered (it has big chapter separated into multiple subchapters), where it is covered over about 50 pages.

Comment: @1muflon1, thanks a lot. Verbeek might be fine; he spends about 30 pages for the basic models that are relevant for me.

Answer (score 3):

As rightly pointed out by @1muflon1@ "Panel data is nowadays quite a big field - usually you will have separate chapters for panel IV, panel logit/probit, panel time series etc".

But if you are "looking for a briefer introduction/overview", I would recommend:

- [Econometrics Training: Module Three Panel Data](https://www.aeaweb.org/about-aea/committees/economic-education/econometrics-training-modules/three) (with William Greene and John Siegfried)

Dates back to 2010, but the authors propose a theoretical part on basic models and an applied part with data and programs.